# Что шлет программа на ком-порт

Tags: com-порт

Есть программа Signur232.exe
https://goo.gl/Qet54h

Она посылает на выбранный ком-порт какой-то сигнал и отображает данные. Как мне узнать что она шлет?

1. Пройтись дизасемблером - но тут я мало что увижу
2. Установить какой-нибудь эмулятор ком-порта и посмотреть запрос (но опять же - скорее всего прога увидит что прибора нет и слать данные не будет, хотя может пошлет в любом случае, а в случае отказа напишет ошибку - на то и расчет)

Какой программой можно узнать что послано на ком-порт?

---

Есть виртуальный ком порт. К нему могу подключить программу и получить значения. Каким образом можно узнать что она послала и что получила?

Answer (score 4):

Если речь идет о работе под Windows, есть такой замечательный open source проект com0com: http://com0com.sourceforge.net/.

Давно с ним не работал, деталей как и что реализовывал не помню, но я на его основе делал передачу данных в com-порт на удаленной машине за счет локально сэмулированного порта (ну и заодно отправлял данные в доп. com-порт, который все выводил в терминал).

Если не ошибаюсь, то там есть модуль, называемый hub4com, который позволяет разветвлять com-порты. Вот на его основе можно направлять данные в какой-нибудь виртуальный терминал (кстати в Windows раньше из коробки какой-то терминал для com-порта был доступен, но название уже не помню), точнее порт, соединенный с терминалом, и параллельно на устройство и следить за этим всем. При чем весь функционал доступен из коробки, только настроить правильно.

Comment: не запускается http://i.imgur.com/0nD1nOY.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Используй *Com Port Visual Control* или подобные утилиты. С их помощью можно отслеживать не только активность программ, но и любых устройств, подключенных к COM-порту

Comment: к ком-порту уже подключена программа - визуализатор. а повторно открыть порт Com Port Visual Control уже не может

Answer (score 1):

Можно аппаратно подключиться к линиями `Rx` и `Tx` с помощью двух других COM-портов и полностью записать весь трафик.

Comment: в наличие нет других ком-портов

Comment: @des1roer проблема дополнительных ком-портов решается установкой мультикарты.